# Make awk print only if matches are greater than 3 and not print if less than 3

Tags: bash, awk

How can I make awk print only if it matches 3 or more and NOT print if it's less than 3.

I'm not strong in awk programming. But here is what  I tried.

```
    awk '/DEF/ {count++;print} { if ( count >  2 ) print count  } ' file
    DEF
```

**DEF** is the result from the command above. It is not suppose to print because there is only one match in the file, not 3 or more.

The pattern DEF is in the file once, but awk still prints it even though I wrote in the if statement to print only if it matches 3 or more. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will print number of line with `DEF` found in the file  more than 2 times (3 or more):

```
awk '/DEF/ {++c} END {if (c>2) print c}' file
```

What if there are two `DEF` on one line, count as one line or two `DEF`?

Print the lines found when there are more than two `DEF` lines found.

```
awk '/DEF/ {++c;a[NR]=$0} END {if (c>2) {for (i in a) print a[i]}}' file
```

This will print a line with number of `DEF` lines found as well as the line.

```
awk '/DEF/ {++c;a[NR]=$0} END {if (c>2) {print "DEF found "c" times";for (i in a) print a[i]}}' file
```

This will print number of hits and line number its found in as well:

```
awk '/DEF/ {++c;a[NR]=$0} END {if (c>2) {print "DEF found "c" times\n-----";for (i in a) {print ++t". line "i": "a[i]}}}' file
DEF found 3 times
-----
1. line 4: DEF first time
2. line 8: red DEF second time
3. line 16: DEF more
```

Comment: It works, but it only shows the count of 3. It doesn't show the matches. Is there a way to show the matches and the count atn  the same time? Thanks

Comment: @thegeek5 Do you what to show all matched lines or just the lines when there are more than two `DEF` is found?  See my update.

Comment: I want to see both the matched lines and the count as well. For example, I want to see DEF and the number 3 or more as well. Is this possible?

Comment: Thanks, that last one did the trick :). THank you, Thank you AND THANK YOU!!! BTW, how do I mark this post solved and give you the credit or reputation for it?

Comment: @thegeek5 You are welcome.  Accept the answer as solved and click the up arrow.

Comment: Just did as you said,  Jotne. Again Thank you and have a great day :)

Comment: @Jotne, someone has given down vote, to nutralize it I upvoted it, cheers.